# how to make smaller system image backups

Tags: windows-backup

I'm looking at making a system image of my laptop onto an external hard drive, however the backup will take over 300GB. I have the space on the hard drive but I would prefer not to use that much space, is there any way of making a smaller system image backup? Would compressing the image make it significantly smaller?

Comment: How big is your C partition and how much space is used from that?

Comment: C partition uses over 300GB, it seems the system image is the same size as the space used on the hard drive

Comment: That's correct. I was hoping you accidentally included other partitions. But in this case, there are very few to none options left. A tip for the future: I always, always, aaaalways set up a PC with C: and D: and change all user folder paths like `My Downloads` , `My Pictures`, `My Videos` and so on to `D:`. Because a system image doesn't need to save pictures or music files. My 5 years old Windows 7 is still 34GB small. I see that this doesn't help. But maybe you can move some of those folders away? Its possible to shrink C: and add D: as new partition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you are stuck with what Windows Backup does.

However, Windows Backup will not attempt to compress files it knows are already compressed.  So once the backup is complete you may be able to gain a few % by compressing it further with 7-Zip/WinRAR. However, for the extra time it will take, much longer than the backup in the first place and minimal gains it is probably not worth it.

Another option is to temporarily move the majority of your user files (Photos, Music etc) to the external device and then create the System Image.  It is not be as clean as what @nixda suggests.

Before experimenting with backups it is always wise to have a good backup on hand.

Answer (score 0):

As for the original post. Normally buy a external disk and put files, vids music etc on that and keep your C clean. It is re imaging what you have on your computer - so save what you want which you should be doing anyway but re image your basic system "set up the way you like."

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can compress the windows backup files with 7zip.  Just did it and got more than 50% size reduction.

Comment: I don't know why they dinged you, John, and I disagree with people that ding and don't explain.  But, look at the accepted answer where it says, " Windows Backup will not attempt to compress files it knows are already compressed. ".  I'd venture a guess that your disks are set as compressed.  Just a thought.